# Using parameters between two jobs with Azure Pipeline templates

Tags: parameter-passing, azure-pipelines

I'm creating parameters in job A and want to use them in Job B, however Job B can not get the parameters value from Job A when I use template. Here is what I am trying:

fetchingfilenames.yml

```
jobs:
 - job: A
   pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
   steps:
   - checkout: myrepo
     persistCredentials: true
   - task: PowerShell@2
     displayName: 'Fetching FileNames'
     inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: |
         Write-Host "Fetching filenames"
         cd $(valuepath)
         Write-Host $(valuepath)
         ##Listing files in the directory and saving them in an array
         $a=ls
         Write-Host "Files:"$a
         $List = $a | foreach {'$(valuepath)/' + $_}
         Write-Host "Files with complete path:"$List
         $b = '"{0}"' -f ($List -join '","')
         Write-Host $b    ####Output is: "$(valuepath)/file1.yml, $(valuepath)/file2.yml"
         Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=valuefiles;isOutput=true]$b"
     name: fileoutput
```

deploy.yml

```
parameters:
  files: []
jobs:
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'  
  variables:
    filenames: ${{ parameters.files }}  
  steps:  
  - checkout: myrepo
    persistCredentials: true
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'mysubscription'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        echo "fetching filenames"
        echo $(filenames)   ####Error: output is empty
        for i in $(echo $(filenames) | sed "s/,/ /g");  ###it doesn't run this line as it seems it can not find $(filename)
        do 
          echo "valuefiles= $i"; 
        done
```

azure-pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - azure-pipeline.yml

variables:
  azureSubscription: 'mysubscription'
  containerRegistry: 'myacr'
  repository: 'myrepo'
  chartPath: 'mypath'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: pipelinetemplates
    type: github
    name: myorg/mytemplates
    endpoint: myendpoint
  - repository: myrepo
    type: github
    name: myorg/myrepo
    endpoint: myendpoint
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master
      paths:
        include:
        - myfolder/*

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  variables:
    azureResourceGroup: 'myresourcegroup'
    kubernetesCluster: 'myk8s'
    domain: 'mydomain'
    valuepath: myfolder   

  jobs:
  - template: Template-Yaml/fetchingfilenames.yml@pipelinetemplates
  - template: Template-Yaml/deploy.yml@pipelinetemplates
    parameters: 
      ##Fetching variable as parameters
      files : $[dependencies.A.outputs['fileoutput.valuefiles']]
```

If I put Job A directly in azure-pipeline.yml and not use template for it, it workes perfectly fine however fetching Job A from template doesn't work as Job B can not fetch the parameter from Job A anymore.

Does anyone know what it is missing here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce above scenario. I can successfully fetch the output variable from Job A template in Job B template.  Could you make sure ` Write-Host $b` in Job A template can output the value when execute azure-pipeline.yml.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT yeah I just ran the pipeline again and I can confirm that I get the output in Job A, which is "myfolder/folder/values.yaml", however in Job B the valuefile is empty: valuefiles=  . can you send me the code that you tested and it worked for you?

Comment: Hi @Matrix  I posted my simple test yamls in below answer, please check it out.

Comment: Hi @Matrix  Did you checkout below yaml? how was it going?

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT I got disconnected, I'm gonna test it this week and will let you know how it went.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I just tested it again by simulating the codes that I have written here on an Azure DevOps and it worked fine. I couldn't test it on the main code as I don't have access to that project anymore, maybe I was missing something there but at least we know that the method is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fetchingfilenames.yml

```
jobs: 
- job: A 
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      cd $(System.defaultworkingdirectory)
      $a=ls
      Write-Host "Files:"$a
      $List = $a | foreach {'$(valuepath)/' + $_}
      Write-Host "Files with complete path:"$List
      $b = '"{0}"' -f ($List -join '","')
      Write-Host $b    
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=valuefiles;isOutput=true]$b"   
    name: power
```

deploy.yml

```
parameters:
  files: []

jobs: 
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables: 
    filenames: ${{parameters.files}}
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      echo $(filenames)
      foreach($a in $(filenames)){write-host $a}
```

azure-pipelines.yml:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: pipelinetemplates
    type: git
    name: PipelineBuildResourceYaml

stages:
- stage: SA
  pool: Default
  variables:
    valuepath: "myfolder"   

  jobs:
  - template: fetchingfilenames.yml@pipelinetemplates
  - template: deploy.yml@pipelinetemplates
    parameters:  
      ##Fetching variable as parameters
      files: $[dependencies.A.outputs['power.valuefiles']]
```

Output of Job B:

[image]